# How do I enforce readonlyness of ref readonly in C# 7.2?

Tags: c#, c#-7.2

I want to write a method returning ref a ref readonly [as described](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md): "The feature allows a member to return variables by reference **without exposing them to mutations.**"

Unfortunately, my code compiles and does such a mutation. How do I make sure it cannot be modified? It is readonly for good reasons. I expect a compiler error. Should I doe something in addition? 200 is modified to 201. I do not want that.

```
internal class TryClass
{
    private static int _result = 0;

    public static ref readonly int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        _result = a * b;
        return ref _result;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;
        var rez = TryClass.Multiply(x, y);
        rez++;
        Console.WriteLine(rez);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @MethodMan I believe you did not read completely the new `ref readonly` syntax in c# 7.2

Comment: You forgot the `ref` keyword before `TryClass.Multiply` (and the corresponding `ref readonly` before `var rez`), thus causing it to return a copy, not a readonly reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types#ref-readonly-returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments. This is is the solution. I get the compiler error I expect: "Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS8329  Cannot use method 'TryClass.Multiply(int, int)' as a ref or out value because it is a readonly variable"

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;
        ref readonly var rez = ref TryClass.Multiply(x, y);
        rez++;
        Console.WriteLine(rez);
        TryClass.DoAfter();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: `ref var rez` should be `ref readonly var rez` (which should lead to a different compilation error)

Comment: To do what? My readonlyness is enforced. "rez++" causes a compiler error.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `rez++` in this code sample? It should still lead to a compilation error

Comment: Yes! And that is exactly what I want. Enforced readonlyness by getting a compiler error when making mutation

Comment: What he's trying to say is that your compilation error isn't on the mutation, it's on the line above it. Remove the mutation completely and you'll get the same compilation error. Your line should look like `ref readonly var = ref TryClass.Multiply(x,y);` Then the compilation error will change to the one you're actually expecting.